# 608 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet]

Tags: java, database, servlets, pentaho

I am using pentaho biserver,and i am getting the following error please help me
Thanks.

```
2011-06-07 11:58:53,886 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.hsqldb.HsqlDatabaseStarterBean] HsqlDatabaseStarterBean.ERROR_0006 - The default port of 9001 is already in use. Do you already have HSQLDB running in another process? The HSQLDB Starter cannot continue.
2011-06-07 11:58:53,8862011-06-07 11:59:33,345 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceSystemListener: PooledDatasourceSystemListener.ERROR_0003 - Unable to pool datasource object: connhyettedb2 caused by org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is ac2011-06-07 12:02:10,492 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceSystemListener: PooledDatasourceSystemListener.ERROR_0003 - Unable to pool datasource object: connhyettedb2 caused by org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2011-06-07 12:02:11,945 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService] Unable to generate EPR for the transport : http
2011-06-07 12:02:12,919 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService] Unable to generate EPR for the transport : http
2011-06-07 12:02:13,111 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService] Unable to generate EPR for the transport : http
2011-06-07 12:02:13,312 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService] Unable to generate EPR for the transport : http
2011-06-07 12:02:13,549 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService] Unable2011-06-07 12:06:04,608 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/modeler_es.properties not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,608 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/main_wizard_panel_es.properties not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,683 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/nativeScripts.js not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,686 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/modeler_es_ES.properties not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,686 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/main_wizard_panel_es_ES.properties not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,714 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /data-access/resources/gwt/gwt-dnd.css not found in plugin Pentaho Data Access
2011-06-07 12:06:04,758 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_es.properties not found in plugin Community Dashboard Editor
2011-06-07 12:06:06,012 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /saiku-ui/saikuplugin_es.properties not found in plugin saiku analytics
2011-06-07 12:06:06,684 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /saiku-ui/saikuplugin_es_ES.properties not found in plugin saiku analytics
2011-06-07 12:06:13,377 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.SystemSettings] ::: SYSTEMSETTINGS.ERROR_0002 - El archivo /opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/cda/settings.xml no existe
2011-06-07 12:06:13,378 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.SystemSettings] ::: SYSTEMSETTINGS.ERROR_0002 - El archivo /opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/cda/settings.xml no existe
2011-06-07 12:06:22,059 WARN  [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: PentahoSystem.WARN_OBJECT_NOT_CONFIGURED - Object with name "IUserDetailsRoleListService" has not been configured in the Pentaho object factory.
```

Comment: "The default port of 9001 is already in use": either use another port or free the port 9001.

Comment: i have changed port number,but then also its giving the same error.please could u help me.

Comment: Does it give the exact same error (with port 9001) or the same error with the new port number? Are you listening on the port ("Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections")?

Answer (score 0):

You have two connectivity issues there.

The first one is to HSQLDB on port 9001. Like the logs say, the 9001 port is already taken. Changing this definition on pentaho is not exactly straightforward, you need to edit some files on the system folder. I'd advise you to free the 9001 port and make it work before you try to change the port.

The second is a connection to a postgres database, maybe defined on context.xml or a datasource created on PUC. Either way, the datasource called connhyettedb2 is not accessible from your server. Check the datasource definitions.

Hope that helps